# ¿Cómo puedo repetir un print en caso de no estar dentro de la lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hace unas semanas que he comenzado con *Python* y tengo una pregunta que por más que he buscado no he encontrado solución. Como puedo repetir el input del principio en caso de que no el numero entrante no este en la lista o no se permita lo escrito??. Gracias a todo el que me ayude.

```
pedir_numero = int(input("Introduce un numero dentro del rango: "))
lista = [1,3,6,9]
if pedir_numero in lista:
    print("El numero introducido se encuentra dentro del rango")
elif pedir_numero is not lista:
    print("Error. El numero introducido se encuentra fuera del rango.")
else:
    print("No se permite lo escrito.")
```

Comment: Lo que necesitas es un bucle `while`. Investiga sobre ello y si sigues teniendo dudas edita la pregunta para indicar qué no has entendido o no te funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con una variable de control y un ciclo `while` que se repita hasta que esa variable de control lo indique, por ejemplo:

```
correcto = False;
lista = [1,3,6,9]
while (not correcto):
    pedir_numero = int(input("Introduce un numero dentro del rango: "))
    if pedir_numero in lista:
        print("El numero introducido se encuentra dentro del rango")
        correcto = True
    else:
        print("Error. El numero introducido se encuentra fuera del rango.")
```

Comoves, he cambiado también tu `if`, ya que si se introduce un valor que no sea numérico, no se llega al último `else`, ya que en la conversión `int()` se lanza una excepción que necesitarías manejar, de otra forma saldría del ciclo y terminaría el programa con un mensaje de error.

Para manejar la excepción, se utiliza un [bloque `try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html), pero ya esa explicación queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta, te dejo el link a la documentación para que te informes sobre la manera de hacerlo.

Volviendo a la repetición, podrías utilizar la propia variable `pedir_numero` si quieres evitar el uso de una variable de control, por ejemplo:

```
lista = [1,3,6,9]
pedir_numero = None
while (pedir_numero not in lista):
    pedir_numero = int(input("Introduce un numero dentro del rango: "))
    if pedir_numero in lista:
        print("El numero introducido se encuentra dentro del rango")
    else:
        print("Error. El numero introducido se encuentra fuera del rango.")
```

Finalmente, también podrías hacerlo con un ciclo infinito, cuya ejecución se rompe al introducir un número completo, usando la sentencia de control `break`:

```
lista = [1,3,6,9]
while True:
    pedir_numero = int(input("Introduce un numero dentro del rango: "))
    if pedir_numero in lista:
        print("El numero introducido se encuentra dentro del rango")
        break
    else:
        print("Error. El numero introducido se encuentra fuera del rango.")
```

Como ves, hay miles de formas de hacerlo. Más que copiar y pegar código, te invito a que entiendas como funciona y construyas tu propia manera de conseguirlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme. La verdad es que aún me cuesta interpretar el codigo y sabía que me faltaba algo pero no sé lo que era, ahora ya lo veo más claro. Le echare un vistazo a la documentación que me has pasado. Saludos